# Writing HTML code for future-proof CSS

Tags: html, css

Looking at the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/), I can see how powerful and convenient it is to separate design and content. The possibilities seem nearly endless. One can change the style sheet and the appearance of the whole site can be drastically altered.

Let's say I'm putting together the HTML part of a website. How do I know where to put divs, where to nest them, etc?

For example, let's say I want to centre something on the screen: I would generally nest 3 divs together: one `display:table`, one `display:table-cell`, and one `margin-left:auto;margin-right;auto` which would have the content.

Let's say I'm just doing the HTML content, but am not thinking about the design at this stage. How would I know that I need to nest together 3 divs if I don't necessarily know I will centre it on the screen?

Or if I have one design now with HTML/CSS and I have my divs and spans all set out, what happens in 18 months if I decide to change the CSS for a completely new layout? Sometimes I will have extra divs and sometimes I won't have enough.

Presumably it would always be better to have more levels than not enough. That way, the worst thing that can happen is that you have a few superfluous divs which aren't styled and have no visible effect.

Is this generally a problem others have? I know CSS Zen Garden is a special case, but would you generally change the HTML code considerably when you change the corresponding CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked in web development for many years, and over here in Reality things are a bit different from Theory: There is no such thing as separation of content and presentation. You'll always end up sliding in additional `div`s.

You better follow the YAGNI principle. Don't worry about your CSS as you're writing your HTML. Come back later and do the neccessary adjustments.

As for Zen Garden, you'll find a comment in the source code:

> This xhtml document is marked up to provide the designer with the maximum possible flexibility. There are more classes and extraneous tags than needed, and in a real world situation, it's more likely that it would be much leaner.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, in order to change the style, you wouldn't have to touch the data (HTML). In practice, there are those problems you mentioned.

What I would do is a more-or-less sensible usage of divs (so for example, anything I think that I might want to move around, or any bunch of HTML that I would want to refer to together - would go in a div of its own). Otherwise, don't use too many divs, for reasons such as readability, maintainability, and size of HTML.
Then, whenever you want to change the style, make the minimal addition of divs so that you'll be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a genuine problem with CSS and it *was* recognised by the authors of CSS3. The most recent [published draft (2003) of the CSS Generated and Replaced Content module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/) discusses a pseudo element called `::outside` which would have solved the problem you describe. It would, when implemented, for

```
<div class="mycontent">Some text</div>
```

have allowed you to write:

```
div.mycontent { margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; }
div.mycontent::outside { display:table-cell; }
div.mycontent::outside(2) { display:table; }
```

Unfortunately, the `::outside` pseudo-element never made it into the CSS3 selectors spec, and the [next draft (2011) of the CSS Generated and Replaced Content module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-content/) will not mention the `::outside` pseudo-element.

So we're stuck with putting wrapper divs everywhere just in case which as you note, does not allow proper separation of presentation and content, and remains a deeply unsatisfactory situation.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how your website is driven. If you are using template files, the amount of updates will be minimal.

You do not want to overload your code with superfluous Divs because a) load time (althought it will be minimal difference in theory) and b) because it will create a lot of confusion when others edit your files.

From your example, it looks like you may be used to table style layouts. Using Divs to contain your layout will make flexibility very easy.